# Adding a new row of data after the last

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data on my Excel file. I want to add new elements to this list by using a userform.
The code below should add the data on column B, one after the data on the last row.

The problem is each time I add a new data, my code deletes the old data.
So if I have data on column B line 3, it deletes what is in line 3 (the last row)  and adds what I've just entered in that line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws_liste As Worksheet
    Dim fin_liste As Integer

    Set ws_liste = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste_Lame_" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value)
    fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A" & Rows.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    'fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A65533").End(xlUp).Row
    ws_liste.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 2) = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Mois.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Annee.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Const.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be `"A" & Rows.Count`.

Comment: Same problem, instead of adding it in line 2 now its been added in line 18

Comment: Why do you refer to A if you are putting things in B?

Comment: Because I need to add othe relements in column C and D, instead of defining evertime a new list I refer to column A and then I specify the column numbe rlike in ws_liste.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 2), 2 is column B

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you use this code

```
fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A" & Rows.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

It always give you value "1" and never change, that's why the new data will delete the old one.

I'll give you two solutions, choose what you want.

First, take one cell to save a value from **fin_liste** as integer (for example I choose cell "D1"). Then add **"i"** for a new variable as integer.
Here the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws_liste As Worksheet
    Dim fin_liste, i As Integer

    Set ws_liste = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste_Lame_" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value)
    fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A" & Rows.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    i = Range("D1").Value + fin_liste
    'fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A65533").End(xlUp).Row
    ws_liste.Cells(i + 1, 2) = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Mois.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Annee.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Const.Value
    Range("D1").Value = i

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

But there's a risk, if value in "D1" has changed, it make your data in a mess.

Second option.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim fin_liste As Range

    Set fin_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste_Lame_" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    'fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A65533").End(xlUp).Row
    fin_liste = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Mois.Value & "-" & Me.TextBox_Annee.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Modele.Value & "-" & Me.ComboBox_Const.Value

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, the second code proposed by @Jek works perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

`ws_liste.Range("A" & Rows.Column).End(xlUp).Row` will evaluate to the first row in the range due to the `xlUp` parameter.

Since you are adding one to the row index in the following line (`ws_liste.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 2)`), I am assuming you are trying to refer to the last row of the range. You can achieve this by using `xlDown` instead of `xlUp`.

```
fin_liste = ws_liste.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Edit: As SJR noted, If there is no data in column A, using `xlDown` on A1 will not find the last row of the data, but instead the next non-blank cell in column A. Instead using `xlDown` on the column that contains the last row of data would be correct.

Comment: No, this is wrong. As established above `Rows.Column` is not correct, and using `xlDown` is not advisable as you may not have anything in column A.

Comment: I agree. `Rows.Column` would evaluate to "A1", but is extremely unnecessary. I have removed that example. I have also included your note about if there is no data being stored in column A, which looks like could be the case.